# Error returning type int8 from a type int

Tags: c++, function, class, constructor, return

So I have these four constructors in my class (the copy is set as default)

```
int8();

explicit int8(short Value);

explicit int8(int Value);

explicit int8(long Value);

int8(const int8& Copy);
```

And this function

```
    int8 int8::Min() {
        return -128; 
    }
```

That gives me this error: No viable conversion from returned value of type 'int' to function return type 'int8'

My question is: how to let compiler to "implicitly" convert the int return value to an int8 type so it can return it?
It works if I explicitly write like this:

```
    int8 int8::Min() {
        return int8(-128); 
    }
```

Or if I remove the explicit keyword in the three constructors. But how can I do if I want to "remove" the brackets and do it writing only the value "-128" maintaining the explicit keyword for the constructors? (I don't know if there is a method but I am curious)

Comment: why do you want this? Making the constructor explicit is exactly for this: To avoid implicit conversions

Comment: *how to let compiler to "implicitly" convert the int return value to an int8 type so it can return it?* The `explicit` keyword prevents the desired **implicit** conversion.

Comment: You could "loosen the belt" by removing `explicit` and adding `template <typename T> int8(T) = delete;` to squelch conversions.

Comment: You could add a [literal operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) so you can write `-128_i8`. But yes; you can't forbid implicit conversions and then complain about it. Either they're allowed or they're forbidden; can't have it both ways.

Comment: Okay so I will remove the keyword, thank you for these comments. I apparently misunderstood the exact meaning of the "explicit" keyword in the constructor